# Maven Integration Testing Framework forces dependency resolution from central repository

Tags: maven, integration-testing, maven-plugin

I'm using the [Maven Integration Testing Framework](https://github.com/khmarbaise/maven-it-extension) plugin to test one goal of a custom-developed plugin. As far as the tests go, everything works well. However, there is one unexpected and undesired technicality that I have noticed:

The local repositories created for individual test cases in `target/maven-it/.../test-case/.m2/repository` are always populated remotely - from the [Maven Central Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/repos/central). If I run `mvn clean integration-test` without being connected to the Internet, the dependency resolution results in an error after a failed connection attempt. I would expect it, however, to look for the dependencies in the "standard" cache located in `USER/.m2/repository` first, where the dependencies were already present in my experiment.

It's interesting that even after adding the `--offline` option to `mvn clean integration-test`, online dependency resolution is still attempted.

My main question is - should this be happening? Is this the expected behavior when using the Maven Integration Testing Framework? Or do you think there might be something wrong with the way I'm using it?

Related dependencies from the `pom.xml` of the tested custom-developed plugin:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-suite</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.platform.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.16.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.soebes.itf.jupiter.extension</groupId>
            <artifactId>itf-jupiter-extension</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.soebes.itf.jupiter.extension</groupId>
            <artifactId>itf-assertj</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Related plugins:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.soebes.itf.jupiter.extension</groupId>
                <artifactId>itf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.11.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>installing</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install</goal>
                            <goal>resources-its</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                  <systemProperties>
                    <maven.version>${maven.version}</maven.version>
                    <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                  </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>integration-test</goal>
                      <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: If the dependencies would be consumed from the users local cache `$HOME/.m2/repository` it could happen that parts which are already in the local cache influence the integration test. That's one of the the reasons each integration tests is completely separated from each other test. Furthermore it makes it possible to parallelise the integration tests. Furthermore you can configure your own `settings.xml` to consume any dependencies from a repository instead directory from central this would also mean that the integration test would consume their deps from that repo manager...

Comment: If this not clear from the documentation etc. please file in an issue so this can be improved in the documentation....or the docs could be enhanced to better explain the behaviour...

Comment: Apart from that the usage of the users local cache would make it impossible (or at least much more complicated) to setup a cache with predefined state (which means already existing artifacts) to test particular scenarios.

Comment: There is also an discussion area on the project https://github.com/khmarbaise/maven-it-extension/discussions where you can ask question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the dependencies would be consumed from the users local cache `$HOME/.m2/repository` it could happen that parts which are already in the local cache influence the integration test. That's one of the the reasons each integration tests is completely separated from each other.

Furthermore it makes it possible to parallelise the integration tests in an easier way.

Furthermore you can configure your own `settings.xml` to consume any dependencies from an repository instead directly from central this would also mean that the integration test would consume their dependencies from that
repo.

Apart from that the usage of the users local cache would make it impossible (or at least much more complicated) to create a local cache with predefined state (which means already existing artifacts) to test particular scenarios.